# How do I make the entire text visible or increase the visible area while using RichTextBox in WP8 SDK to develop an app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, richtextbox

How do I make the entire text visible or increase the visible area while using RichTextBox in WP8 SDK to develop an app? 
Xaml code:

```
        <RichTextBox x:Name="richText"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap">
            <Paragraph Name="contentPara">

            </Paragraph>
        </RichTextBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

c#:

```
Run myRun = new Run();
                    myRun.Text = App.ViewModel.Items[index].LineThree;
                    contentPara.Inlines.Add(myRun);
```

edit:
Entire Xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="horoscope.hdetail"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/background.png" Opacity="0.8" />
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="Bhagawad Gita" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" Height="auto">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
            <!--<Image x:Name="t2"  Width="100" Height="100" Margin="20,0,50,0" />-->
            <TextBlock x:Name="t1" Text="Aries" FontSize="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,20,0" />
        </StackPanel>

            <ScrollViewer Name="scrlvw" Grid.Row="1" Height="auto" Visibility="Visible">

            <RichTextBox x:Name="richText"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                <Paragraph Name="contentPara">

                </Paragraph>
            </RichTextBox>
        </ScrollViewer>


    </Grid>
</Grid>
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" Mode="Minimized">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/questionmark.png" Text="about" Click="ApplicationBarIconButton_Click"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Please help. I am stuck at this for hours and I cant seem to figure out what is the problem.

Here the problem screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Post your full XAML. I'm pretty sure there is a hardcoded `Height` or `VerticalAlignment` somewhere in your XAML.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `ScrollViewer`? It seems that the `RichTextBox`'s [Default Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff457769(v=vs.95).aspx) already has a ScrollViewer.

Comment: ScrollViewer is needed for scrollbar. The text content is huge and it is almost like a book which I am trying to fit on a single page. Removing scrollviewer is disabling the scroll ability and I do not want that. :(

Comment: Please read my comment again. The default `RichTextBox` ControlTemplate already HAS a ScrollViewer.

Comment: But it still does not work. The scroll is disabled after I remove the scrollviewer.

Comment: I tried your full Xaml and it worked correctly. I guess you are seeing this effect after scrolling some text Right?

Comment: Yes. There are no errors. I can see this only in wp8 vm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ScrollViewer.

The [Default RichTextBox Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff457769%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) already has one.

Simply set the [`VerticalScrollBarVisibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.verticalscrollbarvisibility%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property to the RichTextBox, like so:

```
<RichTextBox VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
   <!-- ... -->
</RichTextBox>
```

Comment: The scrolling action does not work after doing this.

Comment: @user2022700 what do you mean by "the scrolling action does not work"? can you be more specific?

Comment: The scrolling does not work in the emulator. A static page with text is the result. It does not display the total page.

Comment: @user2022700 can you post your current XAML and a new screenshot? It really `should` work.

Comment: <RichTextBox x:Name="richText" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                <Paragraph Name="contentPara">

                </Paragraph>
            </RichTextBox>

Comment: @user2022700 Please edit the question and post your full, current XAML, plus a screenshot.